# Simple harmonic motion with pulley with mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, string

The problem is presented in the following diagram

[image]

I'm refreshing things I've already learnt and I know I have some major gaps but I've searched and haven't managed to find a similar problem. The axis of rotation in most of them is at the center of the pulley but here I think it goes through point A in the diagram. Point A seems to be an instantaneous center of rotation. I assume this means that the axis of rotation goes through it. I could be wrong.

This is a problem I've found in some notes and the solution on this problem confuses me a lot. Let's get into the given solution.

We move the object a distance $x$ which translates to a $x/2$ for the spring. 
The author seems to take the sum of torques with respect to point A. The given moment of inertia was $I=1/2MR^2$. Going back to high school I think this stands if the center of rotation is at the center of the pulley. Here, since the center of rotation is at A then the moment of inertia is $I_A=1/2MR^2 + MR^2 $.

Finally, this is the equation used by the author where a is the angular acceleration : 
$$ΣΤ=Ι'a=>\\T2R - k(x/2)R=3/2MR^2 \frac{\ddot x}{R} $$

Since we are taking the torques with respect to A, shouldn't we also have a torque coming from the mass of the pulley? Why doesn't it show up in the equation?

**Update:** 
Moving on, for the object we have: 
$$ΣF=m\ddot x\\T=-m\ddot x$$ 
Plugging this in torque equation we can reach the final equation : 
$$-m\ddot x (2R) - k(x/2)R=3/2MR \ddot x \\=>(3M/2 +2m)\ddot x + (k/2)x=0$$

Which is the standard form of an SHM. 
Now back to my concern. If we had included the weight's torque in the torque equation the new term wouldn't lead to the standard form of an SHM. 
Adding the weight torque, the torque equation with respect to A would be: 
$$ΣΤ=Ι'a=>\\T2R - k(x/2)R + Mgr=3/2MR^2 \frac{\ddot x}{R} $$

Should I or should I not include the weight torque? Why can't I reach a standard form if I include the weight?

Comment: It seems like you are right about everything. The moment of inertia is not $\frac 12 MR^2$ about point A, and the pulley needs to have mass (so that $I$ is not $0$), so its weight does have a non-zero torque about point $A$.

Comment: @AaronStevens Is it possible to take the sum of torques with respect to another point? Will that affect the moment of inertia in the new equation?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to find. You never specified in the question.

Comment: At equilibrium, the all downward forces are cancelled out by the spring force. Note that the spring force and the weight of the pulley act at same point along opposite direction. So, the force and torque due to gravity is always cancelled by a part of the force and torque due to sprint. Generally, in these type of spin block systems, gravity only changes the equilibrium position, it does not affect the frequency

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi But you still need to include it in the equation for torque... It still exists and needs to be included.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi We are not only interested in the equilibrium point. We moved the object and an oscillation has begun.

Comment: Ok so you are looking at the pulley oscillating. If you are interested in the angular acceleration about point A, then you have to use point A as your axis. Therefore your moment of inertia and torques must be about point A. If you were just wondering about equilibrium, then you could choose a different point however.

Comment: If I chose another point, would I have to use a different moment of inertia? Or does $3/2MR^2$ still hold? My main problem was the weight force. I have no trouble with the rest of the problem and that's why I didn't continue my question. What I'm asking now could as well be a new question.

Comment: The problem with picking a new point is that the point is not stationary. I would say the simplest thing to do is use point A. It looks like the solutions you are using are wrong.

Comment: @AaronStevens A similar problem does show up here as well. I edited the question. Can you have a look?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi did provide you with the solution. Stated in other words, you need to examine your definition of $x$. Most likely, this is deviation from equilibrium point, not from relaxation point of the spring. You **can** add $mgr$ as a torque if you like, but than you must define $x$ from relaxation point.

Comment: When you wrote $T = m \ddot x$, you did not notice gravity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in short, yes, you have to consider the torque of gravity.

Suppose, the acceleration of the block (mass $m$) is $a$ (upward) and that of the pulley(mass $M$) is $a/2$.
Suppose, you displace the block by $x$, so the elongation of spring is $x/2$. Let the tension in left string be $T$ and in the right string be $S$.

Thus, $T = mg+ ma$. (Newton's 2nd law on the block).

$kx/2 - T -S - Mg = Ma/2$ (2nd law on pulley)

And, the torque equation is,

$kxR/2 - MgR - 2TR = \frac{3}{2} MR^2 \frac{a}{2R}$ ,

where the angular acceleration of pulley about point A is $\frac{a}{2R}$ (why?). (**Note: it would be much easier to take torques about centre of mass of pulley**, but since you used point A, I too did it)

Eliminating $T,S$ we get,

$a (8m + 3M) = 2kx - 2Mg - 4mg$

where $ a = -\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$.

The time period of the oscillation is $2 \pi \sqrt {\frac{8m+3M}{2k}}$, which is independent of $g$. Note: If you had calculated displacements from equilibrium, then the terms $2Mg - 4mg$ would have been absorbed in it. We can write $2Mg - 4mg =2kx_0$, where $x_0$ is the equilibrium elongation.

Comment: The textbook I'm studying completely ignored gravity forces without mentioning why. Everything is clear with your answer Archisman, thank you.

Comment: @JohnKatsantas  Which textbook?